# python paramiko sftp on Windows returns 'FileNotFound [WinError2]' when trying to use sftp.put(localpath, remotepath)

Tags: python, sftp, filenotfoundexception, paramiko, pysftp

I'm trying to upload a simple file from my local host (Windows) to a remote machine (UNIX) using Python 3.3

Here's the code:

```
import os
import Crypto
import paramiko
import pysftp

localpath = "C:\\py.txt"
remotepath = "/tmp/py.txt"

s = pysftp.Connection(host='10.1.1.1', username='user', password='pass')

s.put(localpath, remotepath)
```

The error which returns is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    s.put(localpath, remotepath)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pysftp.py", line 349, in put
    confirm=confirm)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.14.0-       py3.3.egg\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 585, in put
    file_size = os.stat(localpath).st_size
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C://py.txt'
```

I've tried different prefix for localpath, like 'C:\py.txt' but I get the same results.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `C:\py.txt` should work. Are you sure that you have a file `py.txt` in your C:\ directory?

Comment: Yes I did double check that already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. The problem was with the file location, as it's name was 'py.txt' but my windows didn't show file extensions, so the actual file name was py.txt.txt

Comment: That is why I asked you before that if you have a file named `py.txt`. :) In your case the file name is `py.txt.txt` Don't forget to accept your answer too .

Answer (score 0):

Python uses backslash to quote characters, like `\n` = newline and `\t` = tab; thus `\\\\` = one slash.

Use an `r` prefix to make a raw string literal:

```
localpath = r"C:\\py.txt"
```

Comment: I've tried that, I still get the same error    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\\\py.txt'

Comment: oh sorry: try `localpath = r"py.txt"` -- no `C:` drive prefix.